# Is there a limit to the change in direction of a p-trap assembly at the vertical swivel?

Tags: plumbing, p-trap

I have some IKEA vanities and they are extremely particular about the placement of the p-trap. The p-trap has to be very close / parallel to the wall for the drawers to not bump into the p-trap. I've modified the drain rough opening so that the p-trap will work and the change in direction is close to 180 - is there any problem with that?

[image: p-trap rough fit]

Comment: A view looking straight at it would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

That appears to be fine, though I would agree that an additional picture from a different angle would be helpful. So long as the relationsip of trap parts is maintained, all the rotational freedom they have can be used to make them fit.

**I** would choose a trap with screw connections, rather than what appears to a a "glue it and hope you never have reason to regret that" but both are acceptable for code. Once you have the experience of having to take a saw to one rather than just unscrewing it, you might come to agree with me. If it's not a 2" trap inaccessible under a concrete floor, I want threaded connections.

Comment: I'll grab another picture.  The only thing I could find in code was 135 degree change needs a cleanout - though I think the screw p-trap connection would qualify.  I will switch to the screw connection trap - the glue and pray just happened to be in my part bag.

Answer (score 1):

**It makes absolutely no difference.** To illustrate why, let's break down the individual changes in direction by 90° segments through the trap, beginning with the vertical drop out the tailpiece:

1. To horizontal
2. To vertical (upward)
3. To horizontal
4. Through any horizontal bends to the tee

*None of this changes* when you swing the trap pivots. It's always exactly the same sequence. While a fluid dynamics geek could argue the finer points of the forces involved, the variation is negligible for purposes of an unpressurized drain.